# Reading correct USERProcessHandleQuota in Windows 10

Tags: registry, windows-10

In Windows 10, if you change ...

`SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\USERProcessHandleQuota`

... you can go beyond the 10.000 GDI objects limit for an application.
This is something we willfully want for our application and it works fine.

However, if an app reads this key and value, it ALWAYS returns 10.000 not matter what you have set. It returns 10.000 even if you set 5.000 or any other number. It seems like this is "hardcoded" now?

Is there a way to read the real value stored in this key?

Comment: It does not having anything to do with GDI objects, USER objects are windows and menus.  If you correctly want to read this registry value on a 64-bit version of Windows then you need to target x64 or defeat the registry redirector with KEY_WOW64_64KEY.  Somebody ought to mention what a drastically bad idea this is, but it is exhausting.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. It works. :)